# struts2 getting value in action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

```
<action name="Locator" method="execute" class="LocatorAction">
        <result name="success">/locator/StoreInfo.jsp</result>          
    </action>
```

I have a variable foo in LocatorAction  class and I want to display it on my result jsp, how can I do this?

Comment: Does LocatorAction have a getFoo() public method? If so, what is the output of <s:property value='foo'/> or (cringe) ${foo} in the jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action should look similar to this:

```
public class LocatorAction extends ActionSupport {
      private Foo foo;

      public Foo getFoo() {
           return foo;
      }

      public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
           this.foo = foo;
      }
 }
```

and on the JSP:

```
 <s:property value="foo" />
```

or if the object has fields like address, city, state, zip, etc:

```
 <s:property value="foo.address" /> 
 <s:property value="foo.city" />
 <s:property value="foo.state" />
```

Comment: Good catch on the edit Steven. I guess I'm over reliant on the red squiggly line from my IDE, didn't notice errors typing it directly into here.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of variable into one of the field of form which is binded with the required view and simply display it.